# Next Auth Active Directory override profile with userinfo

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-active-directory, next-auth

I am using Next Auth to authenticate through Azure Active Directory. I am successfully able to do so but the profile object does not contain some info I need.

I am trying to get the "user type" and "account status" properties.

Here's my code

```
providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
        clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
        tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
        userinfo: {
            url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/',
            params: {
                scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read',
                grant_type: 'authorization_code'
            },
        },
    })
]
```

I don't know what to do after this point or even if this is what I should do. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
Here's what I have after changing to what was suggested

```
    providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
        clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
        tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
        userinfo: {
            url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=accountEnabled,userType,displayName,givenName,objectId,email,surname',
            params: {
                scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read',
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            },
        },
        profile(profile) {
            return {
                id: profile.objectId,
                name: profile.displayName,
                lastName: profile.surname,
                firstName: profile.givenName,
                email: profile.email,
                userType: profile.userType,
                accountStatus: profile.accountEnabled
            };
        }
    })]
```

It seems like the profile data from the AzureADProvider is still being used because of the id token. I thought userinfo would overwrite it but it doesn't seem to work that way unless I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to use the request function inside userinfo and fetch the profile data.

```
AzureADProvider({
        clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
        tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
        userinfo: {
            url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,userPrincipalName,accountEnabled,userType,givenName,surname',

            async request(context) {
                const response = await axios.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,userPrincipalName,accountEnabled,userType,givenName,surname',
                    {
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': `Bearer ${context.tokens.access_token}`
                        }
                    }
                )

                const newProfile = await response.data

                return {
                    id: newProfile.id,
                    email: newProfile.userPrincipalName,
                    firstName: newProfile.givenName,
                    lastName: newProfile.surname,
                    userType: newProfile.userType,
                    accountStatus: newProfile.accountEnabled
                };
            }
        },
        profile(userinfo) {
            console.log(userinfo)
            return {
                id: userinfo.id,
                email: userinfo.userPrincipalName,
                firstName: userinfo.givenName,
                lastName: userinfo.surname,
                userType: userinfo.userType,
                accountStatus: userinfo.accountEnabled
            };
        }
    }),
```

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created **Azure AD Application** and granted API permissions:

[image]

I generated the **Access Token using Authorization Code Flow** by using parameters like below:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:RedirectUri
code:code
```

[image]

When I ran the same query as you, I dint get the `userType` and `account status` properties like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

[image]

> **Note** that : By default only businessPhones, displayName, givenName, id, jobTitle, mail, mobilePhone, officeLocation, preferredLanguage, surname, userPrincipalName properties will be returned.

To get the additional user properties, make use of **`$select`** like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=accountEnabled,userType
```

[image]

**Modify the code like below:**

```js
providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
        clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
        tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
        userinfo: {
            url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=accountEnabled,userType',
            params: {
                scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read',
                grant_type: 'authorization_code'
            },
        },
    })
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I updated the code but for some reason its not assigning the userinfo as the new profile data. I will update my post to show my updated code.